# How to use GIFs in Allegro 5 with the Algif5 addon?

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

I try to use this: https://github.com/allefant/algif5 but this doesn't work.

```
#include "algif.h"

char const* pathBoss1 = "boss1.gif";
ALGIF_ANIMATION *boss1Gif = NULL;
boss1Gif = algif_load_animation(pathBoss1);
// in a function: 
al_draw_bitmap(algif_get_bitmap(bossGif, al_get_time()), boss.x, boss.y, 0);
```

It throws lots of bugs like this

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _algif_get_bitmap referenced
>   in function "void __cdecl drawBoss(struct Boss &,struct
>   ALGIF_ANIMATION *)"
>   (?drawBoss@@YAXAAUBoss@@PAUALGIF_ANIMATION@@@Z)   LearnAllegro    C:\Users\User\source\repos\LearnAllegro\LearnAllegro\LearnAllegro.obj   1

As if the library was not found. 
(I put all the downloaded files into ProjectName>ProjectName as there are other .h files there)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official library - instead you need to add  algif.c, bitmap.c, gif.c and lzw.c to your source files.

Alternatively if you know how to create a library you can create a library out of those 4 files and then link against that library.

Comment: I put these files in projectName > projectName and added #include "algif.h". I get these errors: unresolved external symbol _algif_load_animation referenced in function _mainLearnAllegroC:\Users\User\source\repos\LearnAllegro\LearnAllegro\LearnAllegro.objunresolved external symbol _algif_destroy_animation referenced in function _main LearnAllegroC:\Users\User\source\repos\LearnAllegro\LearnAllegro\LearnAllegro.obunresolved external symbol_algif_get_bitmap referenced in function "void__cdecldrawBoss(structBoss &,struct ALGIF_ANIMATION *)"(?drawBoss@@YAXAAUBoss@@PAUALGIF_ANIMATION@@@Z) Learn...

Comment: Do I need to add some other "include" or only this is needed: #include "algif.h"?

Comment: If I add all "include" like this: #include "algif.h"
#include "algif.c"
#include "bitmap.c"
#include "gif.c"
#include "lzw.c"

Comment: ..then there are some other bugs: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'ALGIF_BITMAP *'LearnAllegro c:\users\user\source\repos\learnallegro\learnallegro\bitmap.c4 ErrorC2440'=': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'uint8_t *'LearnAllegroc:\users\user\source\repos\learnallegro\learnallegro\bitmap.c7
ErrorC2440'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'ALGIF_ANIMATION *' LearnAllegroc:\users\user\source\repos\learnallegro\learnallegro\gif.c 69 
ErrorC2440'=': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'ALGIF_FRAME *'LearnAllegroc:\users\user\source\repos\learnallegro\learnallegro\gif.c158

Comment: make sure to compile those files as C and not as C++

Comment: So my program is in C++ and this extension is in C. What exacly should I do to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The library did not work for me and I ended up inputting gif frames separately. This for loop I used might help you: 
A simplified version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxFrameBoss1; i++) {
    std::string filename;
    filename = "boss1//frame_" + std::to_string(i) + "_delay-0.03s.png";


    boss1Image[i] = al_load_bitmap(filename.c_str());
    if (!boss1Image[i]) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create boss1Image bitmap!\n");
        return -1*i;
    }
}
```

Make sure to include this at the beginning of your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```